# Reactjs SPA app - Everything as a component (Performance and practices)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see that react fits well when you want to "componentize" small parts of your application, but I'm not sure about making a full component application, let's say a SPA.

In my example I have a single page with a menu and a content place for the "views" that are other components as well.

The way I found to solve that is to build a menu component and on its render method I check what option has been chosen and display this in this content place, its nothing but a switch case inside the render method (Smells but easily to fix)

```
var MenuComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { selectedPage: '' }
  },
  handleMenuClick: function(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedPage: e.target.attributes['data-page'].value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='main'>
        <ul class='menu'>
          <li><button onClick={this.handleMenuClick} data-page='applicantList'>Applicant List</button></li>
          <li><button onClick={this.handleMenuClick} data-page='applicantForm'>Applicant Form</button></li>
        </ul>
        <div className='content'>
          {function() { 
            switch(this.state.selectedPage) {
              case 'applicantList':
                return <ApplicantList />
              case 'applicantForm':
                return <ApplicantForm />
              default:
                return <h1>Select a Page</h1>
            };
          }.bind(this)()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

From that point I imagine everything being a component and having their children components and so on. I want to know if this approach is a good practice and if it has drawbacks like performance or maintainability (I found it far easier for unit testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting up your app into many small components is a great idea as it tends to make things a lot easier to understand. Think of each component as a function whose arguments are the props; with that in mind, perhaps it's a little more obvious the advantages of splitting things up like you suggest.

Unit testing is a great reason but splitting into components like this also tends to make code simpler, so I'd definitely recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Any consideration for performance ? Let's say I'd 30 views where each one would be broken down into many other components, with statuses handling and so on. In the example I've provided it would have to require all of those components.

Comment: Components are very cheap and have barely any performance impact. In fact, using more components gives you the opportunity to make _more_ optimizations in the form of [`shouldComponentUpdate` methods](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) in the right places.